# Mapbox gl directions API

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

So I am writing an app which allows an admin user to create a journey around a specific location with different stopping points.

For displaying a map, adding markers, flyTo location and etc I am using `Mapbox GL`.

I was using `cURL` implementation of `Mapbox` API to get driving directions and then draw a line on a map

So as an example of a `cURL` call I recieve a list of coordinates which represent my directions.

**The Problem** comes when I try to connect these points on a map.

As an example of `HTML` with some `JS`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<ACCESS TOKEN>';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8',
    center: [-122.486052, 37.830348],
    zoom: 15
});

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource("route", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                 [-155.088899,19.722942],[-155.08565,19.72472],[-155.084661,19.723701],[-155.083569,19.723139],[-155.079557,19.722262],[-155.074227,19.721938],[-155.069939,19.722545],[-155.070061,19.721225],[-155.07007,19.711726]
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "route",
        "layout": {
            "line-join": "round",
            "line-cap": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#888",
            "line-width": 8
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see a set of coordinates that will be connected to draw a line. I was wondering if there is a way to connect these points so that the line will follow only the road (for driving)?

To explain it better, this is a close zoom of the output
[image: mapbox gl connect set of points with a line]

I know it's quite generic explanation of my problem, but I hope it's understandable.

I have been trying to do some magic with `Mapbox Gl Directions API` but no luck, as I have to add a `contoller` which I dont want to. I only need to draw a route and not allow a public user to be able to modify it.

Any advices?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually it was easier that I thought, All I had to do is to get a response from directions API, and pass a returned array to Mapbox Map Matching, that way it returns a perfect route. All documented in Mapbox API

Comment: can u check this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255333/get-directions-between-two-points-in-mapbox

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but when you send you request to get directions  include in the url '**overview=full'**. This will return a more detailed path, so you have no need to use Matching API after.

Example:
`https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/-74.50,40;-80,50?overview=full&geometries=geojson&access_token=

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to do this today and succeded to get directions into a map and remove the start and end control by pulling down the mapbox-gl-directions project from git hub and making a minor mod to src/directions.js

I commented out lines 48 to 52

```
// Add controllers to the page
//new Inputs(inputEl, store, this.actions, this.map);
//new Instructions(directionsEl, store, {
//  hoverMarker: this.actions.hoverMarker,
//  setRouteIndex: this.actions.setRouteIndex
//}, this.map);
```

This was relatively easy to test with the setup in npm and my own test files by running the npm setup as per https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

```
npm install & npm start & open http://localhost:9966/example/
```

I also added the line:

```
localStorage.setItem('MapboxAccessToken', '<TOKEN HERE>');
```

below the require('../); in example/index.js. While you have the example running in npm you can access a new bundled version of the plugin from http://localhost:9966/example/bundle.js

I was then able to change the line

```
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl-directions.js'></script>
```

to

```
<script src='http://localhost:9966/example/bundle.js'></script>
```

There's a whole bunch of magic going in on in the example runner in npm which I don't know anything about but it all just worked on my machine. Hope this helps. The directions line works with animations and pitch, zoom and bearing animations. See a screen grab below:

[image]

UPDATE: Adding reply to here so I can show a screen grab. @Andrejus, as this hack relies on the mapbox gl directions plugin behaviour rather than drawing the paths from scratch you get road following built in and you have access to the directions API to add waypoints to do your A->B->C->D as so:

```
map.on('load', function() {
    directions.setOrigin(start); 
    directions.addWaypoint(0, [-0.07571203, 51.51424049]);
    directions.addWaypoint(1, [-0.12416858, 51.50779757]);
    directions.setDestination(end);  
});
```

The documentation says you can have up to 25 way points.

[image]

The mapbox-gl-directions plugin doesn't have an option to turn off the on-screen controls, they are added in the onAdd(map) method of the Directions class which is called when the directions are added to the map. I wanted to see if I could remove them earlier and was experimenting, thus the hack. To make a flexible solution, it might be possible to add an option passed in to the constructor of the Directions class. There are other options passed in there although these seem to be bound to parameters for the call to the Directions API:

```
var directions = new mapboxgl.Directions({
  unit: 'metric',
  profile: 'cycling'
});
```

So there might be a better solution than that. I've been using Mapbox for <1 day and don't know much about how its written or structured.

Note also that the code alterations are in a plugin, not the core of mapbox gl, so relatively isolated. BTW this plugin is a wrapper for the cURL API you were calling which returned the array of points. Presumably the source on GitHub will include code which does the road following where it renders the line, if that's definitely what you want to do.

Comment: hmm, interesting approach, although to me this sounds like a hack. What I also want is an extensibility to create routes like from A->B->C->D following this pattern. But I still like your way!

Comment: @AndrejsGubars: I updated the answer above with some more notes on adding waypoints as you were asking for that. Also added some notes on making a solution. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, spot on! Thats exactly what I wanted to do. I guess I was too ambitious and was expecting something that a whole library does :) But thank you for your advices!

Comment: Hello @StevenPavett can u check this question please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255333/get-directions-between-two-points-in-mapbox